# Selenium/Chromedriver: Turn off location for a single site

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

When I run chromedriver, due to my system preferences it turns off "Location" as shown in this image. [image: location being turned off]
The problem is an individual site still think my location is allowed. As shown in this image:
[image: site thinking location is allowed]
When I manually set this drop-down to "block" then I achieve the desired behavior. Any way to do this programmatically? Here is what I've tried adding in the capabilities/preferences from various posts around the internet, none have worked:
`--disable-geolocation`
`--enable-strict-powerful-feature-restrictions`
`profile.default_content_settings.geolocation: 2`
`geolocation: 1`

Comment: please add an example website and language binding you are using ( like java , python etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> --deny-permission-prompts

Prevents permission prompts from appearing by denying instead of showing prompts. ↪

https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

COuld you try adding this as argument example :7

**python ;**

```
options.add_argument('--deny-permission-prompts')
```

Comment: This sort of works! But with an exception. Previously I was trying to navigate to problemURL right after creating the webdriver. However, if I navigated to "chrome://settings/content/location" FIRST then navigated to my desired URL the location pop-up will come up (and get denied because of the cli switch). Weirdly enough, this doesnt occur if I go to some other url first (like Google.com) and note I am not toggling any of the chrome setting switches, just visiting the page.

Comment: What happened when u visit Google then settings then your desired url. I don't have an example websit to try out

Comment: Works as it should (location = blocked)